# How to upload from phpmyadmin articles with different structures using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I want to create articles and store them in phpmyadmin, then with PHP I would upload them to the webpage. There is no problem if all the articles have the same sctructure, but as it is normal, some articles may have 1 image, other 2 images or more...different amount of quotes...

For example.

One article has 1 image and no more, so the article sctructre could be something like:

```
<div class="article">

<img src="documents/image.png" alt="image">
<h1>First article with no image inside</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
    fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>    
</div>
```

Another article with 1 image and a quote inside:

```
<div class="article">

<img src="documents/image.png" alt="image">
<h1>Second article with 1 image and a quote inside</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
    fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <h2 clas="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>

    <img src="documents/another.png" alt="image">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
    fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

 </div>
```

I don't know how to deal with this "problem". If all the articles had the same structure would be simple.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Why don't you want to store full article in single text field as is?

Comment: @KostyaShkryob cause I couldn't introduce an image between two paragraphs for example.